# No connection to generic driver

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine

I have a remote Ubuntu VM (16.04) where I installed Docker (v1.13.1).

- `$ sudo service docker status` tells me that the service is active (running).
- I opened ports 2375 and 2376 via `$ sudo ufw allow 2375 && sudo ufw allow 2376`.
- I created a sudo user called `docker` and added the line `docker     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` inside `/etc/sudoers`.
- I copied content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (local) to `/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys` (remote).

But now, when I try to execute `$ docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ip-address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --generic-ssh-user docker myhost` (on my local machine) I get

```
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

And with `$ docker-machine ls` my host is listed, but with an Error message:

```
Unable to query docker version: Get https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2376/v1.15/version: dial tcp XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you ssh to the host as docker?

Comment: Yes, with password authentication. (not sure about the thing with the ssh key)

Comment: Shouldn't need a password if you copied your public key over.

Comment: So what did I do wrong?